# Does MS Teams work with non-cloud version of MS Office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, microsoft-office-2019

I purchased Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019, which is a non-subscription version of Office, installed on my home PC.  Skype is bundled with the offering.  Because I am not logging into a Microsoft account, will Teams integrate into Outlook the same way it does when using the MS 365 Office suite?

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to work like that:[Use the Teams Meeting add-in in Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-add-in-for-outlook). Also, according to my experience, if you had enabled the Microsoft Teams add-in in one Exchange email account, when adding this account to new Outlook clients, Outlook will automatically sync this add-in to local clients.